# Existence of a continuous holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume a continuous function f: {|x| = 1} $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}$, is it correct that we can always find a continuous function g: $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}$ such that it is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and coincides with f(x) on {|x| = 1} ?

Just wondering which theorem is helpful to solve it? Is it reflection principle?

Comment: Consider the function $e^{it}\mapsto e^{-it}$ and compute the residue at $z=0$. For analytic one would expect residue equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\T}{\mathrm{T}}$
$\newcommand{\D}{\mathrm{D}}$

Write $\T$ for the unit circle, $\D$ for the open disc, $C(\T)$ for continuous complex-valued maps on the circle, $A(\D)$ for [the space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Boundary_properties_of_analytic_functions) of holomorphic maps on $\D$ that are continuous on the closure $\overline{\D}$. Write $G$ for the map

$$\begin{align}G&:C(\T)\to A(\D)&
G[\phi](z)=\oint_{\T}\frac{\zeta+z}{\zeta-z}\phi(\zeta)\frac{\mathrm{d}\zeta}{2\pi\mathrm{i}\zeta}
\end{align}$$

Let  $f$ belong to $A(\D)$. Then the [Schwarz integral formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Schwarz_integral) says that

1. when restricted to the open disk $\D$, $f$ is recoverable from its restriction $f\rvert_{\T}$ to $\T$ and its value at the origin $f(0)$ via $$f(z)=\tfrac{1}{2}\left(G[f\rvert_{\T}](z)+f(0)\right)\text{,}$$ and
2. the map $G$ annihilates conjugates of holomorphic functions up to a constant: $$G[\overline{f\rvert_T}](z)=\overline{f(0)}\text{.}$$

Note the contrapositive of the second part: *if $G[\overline{\phi}](z)$ is not a constant, then $\phi$ is not the boundary value of a holomorphic function*! In particular, none of "left-handed modes" $\phi(\zeta)=\zeta^{-n}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ can be such a boundary value, as using residue calculus for this special case shows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation from a harmonic function point of view. By the Poisson integral formula, there exists a unique real harmonic function $u$ in $\mathbb{D}$ satisfying $u=\mathrm{Re}f$ on the boundary $\partial\mathbb{D}$. Once $u$ is given, its harmonic conjugate $v$ is determined up to a constant, giving a holomorphic function $g=u+iv$ in $\mathbb{D}$. Thus, specifying the full value $f$ on the boundary $\partial\mathbb{D}$ would be in general an overdetermined problem. Intuitively speaking, only a "half" of $f$ is enough to fix $g$ uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

The space you want is called $A$ and has a lot of interesting properties; it can be described as the norm closure of polynomials on the unit circle - or equivalently the continuous functions on the circle with Fourier series that has no $e^{-in\theta}, n>0$ term in its expansion.

Some cool results about it are that if $f \in A, f$ not the zero function, $\log |f|$ is Lebesgue integrable on the unit circle - in particular, the set of zeroes of $f$ on the unit circle has measure zero (and is closed) and conversely, every closed set of measure zero has some such $f$ with its zero set the given one, $A$ is a maximal closed (Banach) subalgebra of the algebra of the continuous functions on the circle, its maximal ideals are given by $M_{\lambda}=$ the set of $f \in A, f(\lambda)=0$, for $\lambda$ fixed in the closed **unit disc** (where we let $f$ be the analytic extension to the unit disc too). Its closed ideals are all principal, while its primary closed ideals can be explicitly described.